# Какие параметры надо передать в transforms.Normalize()?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

Нашел готовый код на pytorch, там:

```
torchvision.transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
```

Но согласно документации числа, которые мы передаем, должны быть вычислены предварительно для нашего набора данных.

Как вычислить эти числа?

Comment: Если это [`torchvision.transforms.Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize), то на вход передаются среднее и отклонение для каждого канала.

Comment: @hoefling
Это я понял, а как вычислить среднее и отклонение для каждого канала? Я новичок и не очень понимаю, что это такое и как вычислить

Comment: Среднее: [`torch.mean()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html), отклонение: [`torch.std()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.std.html).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю? Если у меня 9000 3-х канальных изображений, то каждое изображение надо преобразовать в тензор, для каждого вычислить mean и std, а потом усредненное значение mean и std отправить в normalize

Comment: Не совсем - среднее и отклонение ты задаешь целевые. Если ты знаешь заранее, с какими данными работаешь (в данном случае - с числами от 0 до 255, каждое изображение - три канала по цветам RGB), задавая разные значения среднего и отклонения, можно нормализовать данные по-разному. К примеру, тензор чисел между 0 и 1: `x = torch.rand((3, 5, 5))` функция `f = Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])`, вызов `f(x)` нормализует к интервалу между -1 и 1.

Comment: Я понял, как работает нормализация и почему [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5] нормализует к интервалу между -1 и 1. Но я не понимаю зачем по-разному нормализовать для каждого изображения. Почему все нельзя нормализовать к -1 и 1

Answer (score 2):

Среднее и стандартное отклонение высчитывается для **всего** набора картинок. Значения из вашего вопроса - это среднее и отклонение для всего набора ImageNet. Для того, чтобы посчитать данные значения для вашего набора данных нужно посчитать среднее и стандартное отклонение для всех картинок из вашего набора данных.